# How to replace some characters in tsv file like HTML Math and Engineering symbol entities

Tags: php

Actually i want to replace these HTML Math and Engineering symbol entities numbers. With there equivalent code like `¼ to &#188;` and `½ to &#189;`.

[Examples are given in link below](https://www.developphp.com/page.php?id=684).

I have used `str_replace` and `preg_match` but non of them worked. SO Please tell me a way to do this. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you please provide what hasn't worked, what your input is, and what the output should be?

Comment: I am using a .tsv file in which following content is returning
Count of 100 Medium Black & Silver Swirl Paper Shopping Bag 8" x 4 ½" x 10 ¼
Case of 100 New Medium Durable Navy Blue Paper Shopping Bag 8" x 4 ½" x 10 ¼"
I am using wordpress environment whenever i output the .tsv file the figure ¼,½,⅖,⅘,⅚ are not converted to there equivalent code like &#188 or &#189 etc.And whenever i insert this content in database it shows somethis else encoded.I have tried str_replace and preg_match both didn't worked :\

Comment: If you have any questions or issues with the answer below please post them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the mb_encode_numericentity function to do this, http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-encode-numericentity.php

```
$string = '¼ ½ ⅖ ⅘ ⅚ ';
$convmap= array(0x0080, 0xffff, 0, 0xffff);
$string = mb_encode_numericentity($string, $convmap, 'UTF-8');
echo $string;
```

Output:

> `&#188; &#189; &#8534; &#8536; &#8538;`

Demo: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c554aae1696c8ded4cdd97329269828c4cbf836b

Note: This will convert other characters outside the ascii character set. If you only want to convert those 5 characters str_replace might be a better route.

```
$string = ' the figure ¼,½,⅖,⅘,⅚ are not';
$find = array('¼', '½', '⅖', '⅘', '⅚');
$replace = array('&#188;', '&#189;', '&#8534;', '&#8536;', '&#8538;');
echo str_replace($find, $replace, $string);
```

Output:

> `the figure &#188;,&#189;,&#8534;,&#8536;,&#8538; are not`

Demo: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e17eabdef9eabcf4f5bf4f607edddd9ac3779c75